# How to remove horizontal line from this x-ray image?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm new in opencv (c++) and I want to remove horizontal line from this x-ray image. But I can not.

These is my image:

[image]

What ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

This is my c++ code

```
src = imread("C:/Users/Alireza/Desktop/New folder (3)/11.bmp");
cvtColor(src, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
imshow("Original Image", gray);
imwrite("Original Image.png", gray);
normalize(gray, gray, 0, 250, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
threshold(gray, thresh, 170, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
vector< vector <Point> > contours;        
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
int largest_contour_index = 0;
int largest_area = 0;
Mat alpha(src.size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
findContours(thresh, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)                                
{
double a = contourArea(contours[i], false); 
if (a>largest_area)
{
largest_area = a;
largest_contour_index =     i;                                                                
}
}
drawContours(alpha, contours,     largest_contour_index,Scalar(255),CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy);         
vector<Mat> rgb;
split(src, rgb);
Mat rgba[4] = { rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], alpha };
merge(rgba, 4, Tafrigh);
imshow("Tafrigh", Tafrigh);
imwrite("Tafrigh.png", Tafrigh);
```

Comment: you can see more images in http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=60368569977646932463 and http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=17335973361892920384.

Comment: Your question should contain the code and maybe also the image. I will not download some file, just to see your code.

Comment: @ tobi303: I can not insert my code. System don't  allow to me insert my code!!! you can click on code.cpp in that page and it starts opening.

Comment: How do you scan such x-ray images?

Comment: Thank you so much for edit.

Comment: This image scan with system security.

Comment: Looks like you need to calibrate your input device. Does it have a calibration procedure? I don't think it should be so randomly different from one scanline to the next. A device like this should have a procedure where it scans nothing and gets a baseline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a 2D FFT, take a look at the spectrum. You will see plenty of dots along the center y-axis. Suppress those dots , back transform, your vertical lines will be gone.

Below the result (since I don't have C++ and opencv installed) in Python, with sliders to vary the region to be suppressed. Consider it Pseudocode. This is still pretty rough as I'm not making a smooth transition between suppressed pixels and their neighbors here for simplicity.

```
%matplotlib inline
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from ipywidgets import *

from scipy import misc
f = misc.imread('xray_image_with_horizontal_lines.png')

a=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(f)) 

def process(kx,ky):
    p.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    p.subplot(221)
    p.imshow(f, cmap=p.cm.gray)
    p.subplot(222)
    p.imshow(np.abs(np.log(a)), cmap=p.cm.gray)

    print np.shape(a)
    b=np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in range(639):
        for j in range(406):
            if not ( 320-kx<i<320+kx and (j<203-ky or j>203+ky)):
                b[j,i]=a[j,i]

    c=np.fft.ifft2(b)
    p.subplot(223)
    p.imshow(np.abs(np.log(b)), cmap=p.cm.gray)
    p.subplot(224)
    p.imshow(np.abs(c), cmap=p.cm.gray)  

interact(process, kx=[1,20,1],ky=[1,20,1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's just an idea : keep mean line constant.

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("Tf6HO.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
vector<double> moyenne;
double minval,maxval;
minMaxLoc(image,&minval,&maxval);
imshow("original",image);
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{
    double s=0;
// Caluclate mean for row i
    for (int j=0;j<image.cols;j++)
        s += image.at<uchar>(i,j);
// Store result in vector moyenne
    moyenne.push_back(s/image.cols);
}
// Energy for row i equal to a weighted mean of row in [i-nbInf,i+nbSup]
int nbInf=32,nbSup=0;
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{
    double s=0,p=0;
    // weighted mean (border effect process with max and min method
    for (int j = max(0, i - nbInf); j <= min(image.rows - 1, i + nbSup); j++)
    {
        s+=moyenne[j]*1./(1+abs(i-j));
        p+=1./(1+abs(i-j));
    }
    // Weighted mean
    s/=p;
    // process pixel in row i : mean of row i equal to s 
    for (int j=0;j<image.cols;j++)
        image.at<uchar>(i,j) =saturate_cast<uchar>((image.at<uchar>(i,j)-moyenne[i])+s);
}
imshow("process",image);
waitKey();
```

[image: result]
or with reduce resolution
[image]

if you want to improve you can read this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3749244/) and bibliography

Comment: @ LBerger: Thank you so much for your code. If it possible, please explain integer numbers "nbInf" -"nbSup" - "Energy" in your code and explain "keep mean line constant" algorithm.

Comment: Principle is keep   1-> mean line (line 6-14) constant and 2-> but mean line is following neighboroud mean  line : a weighted mean line is estimated

Comment: @ LBerger: Thank you so much for your guide. I'm new in image processing and I don't understand your algorithm. I want to perfectly explain your algorithm for my friends, But I can't it. If it possible perfectly explain your algorithm for me. Thanks a lot.